# making custom component in android

Tags: android, components

I am new in android, I dont have that much of experience. I want to know making a custom component. I followed http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html. But many things are not getting cleared. Recently I visited a link http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/source/browse/trunk/wheel/src/kankan/wheel/widget/WheelView.java?r=4. There they have made custom component. 
Please suggest me a well documented tutorial where I will get a clear picture about making custom component where onMeasure(int,int), onDraw(Canvas) all methods will be used and all the things will be documented well, why we are using this?

Please suggest me such a link or tutorial. I really want to be confident in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is somewhat unclear. What kind of custom components do you want to make. Just regular views? Viewgroups or perhaps custom adapters? You will probably find plenty of good material if you search more precise.

But to start you of with some: 
http://www.anddev.org/creating_custom_views_-_the_togglebutton-t310.html

http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/custom-views-t1891.html

Since I am a new user I can't post more links.

Comment: thank you David, you caught me right. I want to focus on regular views, viewgroups and custom adapters mainly. Thanks for your suggested links. Let me go through those.